# Is it possible to teach Smeargle HM moves via Sketch in gen 2?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I've read online that Smeargle can learn any move via Sketch.

Is there any opportunity in the 2nd generation to allow Smeargle to learn HM moves in this fashion, without using a link-cable?

I'm unsure if any trainers know HM moves, and if not, whether there would be a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smeargle can learn HM moves by using Sketch, but no trainer has any Pokémon that knows an HM move, and no Pokémon can naturally learn an HM move.

Additionally, after a Link Battle both players' parties are returned to their status right before the battle. Consumed items are restored, and Sketched moves are lost, so asking for another player's help won't work.

If you're set on wanting to teach Smeargle HM moves, you would need to have a wild Smeargle Sketch the move, then have your own Smeargle Sketch it in turn. A wild Pokémon with Mimic would work as well, but Sudowoodo is the only Pokémon to learn it in generation 2 games.